# How to center a div with many elements

Tags: html, css, frontend, element, center

I'm trying to center my div in html code. It has image and texts also, so when I try centering it div changes it's form.  I tried it by adding  display: flex; in my div element but images and texts goes to one place and they cover each other.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #d5e1ef;
}

div {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="./image-qr-code.png" />
  <h1>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h1>
  <p>
    Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you want the div to be in the center of the screen?

Comment: Please specify whether you mean horizontal centering, vertical centering, or both.

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

You can use `margin: 0 auto;` to align the center your entire `div`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are trying to center the content verticaly:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the div.

use f`lex-direction: column;` to align your element vertically.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: #d5e1ef;

}

div {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 40vh;
  min-height: fit-content;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;

  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="./image-qr-code.png" />
      <h1>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h1>
      <p>
        Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to
        the next level
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
```